# Make button save file as "field1+filed2

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have some VBA that inserts the contents of a couple fields from a form into a spreadsheet. Rather then opening the doc I would like it to save the doc as "txtCustomerNumber + txtCustomerName". I've been toying with the code below a little and can't seem to get it right.

```
Private Sub cmdMCF_Click()
    Dim appExcel As Excel.Application
    Dim wbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim wsheet As Excel.Worksheet

    Set appExcel = New Excel.Application
    appExcel.Visible = True
    Set wbook = appExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents\MySpreadsheet.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True)
    Set wsheet = wbook.Worksheets("MCF")

    With wsheet
        .Cells(10, 1).Value = txtCustomerName
        .Cells(10, 2).Value = txtCustomerNumber
        .Cells(10, 3).Value = txtAddress + " " + txtCity + " " + txtState + " " + txtzip

        .Cells(12, 1).Value = txtPhone
        .Cells(12, 2).Value = txtEmail
        .Cells(12, 3).Value = txtmeasurenumber

        .Cells(14, 1).Value = txtStore
        .Cells(14, 2).Value = cboIP
        .Cells(14, 3).Value = txtIPPhone1

    End With

End Sub
```

Current Workflow: When a user clicks the cmdMCF button a spreadsheet opens with some information from the record they were viewing. The user then saves the spreadsheet to a network folder with the format above then emails that spreadsheet to vendors.

Envisioned workflow: When a user clicks the cmdMCF button the spreadsheet does not open but just saves to that network folder. The user then emails it to the vendor/s.

Comment: I don't see where you're saving anything...

Comment: and how it should accept any changed when you open them as "ReadOnly:=True"  :D 
perform wBook.saveas "filename", (Version/Extention number)

Comment: What happens when you try to run that code?

Comment: HansUP: It opens the spreadsheet filled out with info from the record displayed on the form the user is looking at. That process replaced one where the users typed the data in manually because we were seeing a lot of errors.

Comment: Krish: Good point. That ReadOnly was in there so users couldn't keep saving over and changing the original form.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the values are from text boxes. For VBA use &

```
.Cells(10, 3).Value = txtAddress.text & " " & txtCity.text & " " & txtState.text & " " & txtzip.text
```

And for saving apply it to the workbook.

```
wbook.SaveAs SaveAs Filename:="C:\temp\" & txtCustomerNumber.text & txtCustomerName.text, FileFormat:=xlWorkbookNormal
```

Comment: I'm having some trouble with this throwing various errors.